# How to offset the edges?

Tags: edges

I want to offset the edges. An reference.gif is attached. I have done in other software. Can we offset the edges in that way.[image]

Comment: Use the *Inset* operator, by default `i` key

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I Inset a face equally?](http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/50876/how-do-i-inset-a-face-equally or http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/52308/how-to-extrude-and-scale-with-an-even-offset/52313#52313

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can.  Download and install the offset addon.  You can find the source code here:
https://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Extensions:2.6/Py/Scripts/Modeling/offset_edges

You can find the compiled script (mesh_offset_edges.py) here: https://developer.blender.org/F100890

Put the file in your ..\Blender\2.xx\scripts\addons directory.  Then, in Blender, bring up User Preferences and click on the Addons tab.  At the bottom, click on "Install from file".  Find the file and click on it.

Comment: Thanks for replying there is no download button to install. I have copied all the text and paste in notepad and save the file with .py it install but when click on activate its give me error. Can u give me solution plz

Comment: I've modified my answer.  You should be able to find the executable file (

Comment: can we add 3-4 offset (i mean from small to big) i cant find the option.

Comment: In Edit mode > Mesh > Edges, you should see "Offset Edges >" at the bottom.  Expand that and choose you option.  Then, either at the bottom of the Tool Panel or after pressing F6, set the direction and distance you want.

Comment: u did not get what i mean the addon is superb i mean can is there any option in that addon only 1 offset at a time can we have 3-4 edge offset at one click

Comment: it creates offset but it doesnt create faces. Above gif creates offset and faces. Is there any addon or how can i make offset and faces both same time.

Comment: Not working with 2.79. Installs (from locally downloaded file) but has no entry in Edges menu in Edit mode.