# How to create a hole in a rotated face and choose the distance between the external and internal edge?

Tags: modeling, mesh, edges, measurement

[image]

I want to create a square hole in a wall, but I would like the space between the external and internal edges to have a specific measurement (0.005 m). I succeeded to do it on one wall because it is aligned with Global Orientation, but the wall where I want to create the hole is rotated, making it much more challenging for me as a beginner.

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/52308/how-to-extrude-and-scale-with-an-even-offset https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/50876/how-do-i-inset-a-face-equally https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/1088/is-there-a-way-to-offset-an-edge-extrude-edge-loop-perpendicular-to-each-edge/ https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/14868/inset-in-blender-not-coming-out-even/