Extrude faces evenly on rectangle
 "I want to extrude the faces evenly on this rectangle, but when I try to extrude, it's not working." please help, thanks

https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/50876/how-do-i-inset-a-face-equally

@DuarteFarrajotaRamos thanks , its working
